# Navigation Drawer not working my Code in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I am working with Navigation Drawer in Android.I have code from some examples.In my code working to change the drawer open and drawer close title but the panel is not open.I not insert the ListView array. My main Problem is not open the panel.Is anything I missed in the code?

`layout_mynavigation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"/>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`MyNavigation.java`

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MyDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_mydrawer);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_closed) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle( R.string.drawer_open );
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle( R.string.drawer_closed );
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged( newConfig );
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return mActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

`styles.xml`

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Is that an empty ListView?

Comment: @karaokyo ya ..If the panel is open I can able to add ListView..

Comment: The problem with these answers is that they do solve your issue, but they are wrong in that they don't actually explain correctly why.

Comment: that is considered vote fraud and will eventually be reversed, so don't do it

Comment: @karaokyo haha ..ok ..I stopped .Sorry for that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DrawerLayout` expects it's first child to be the actual layout and the second one to be the drawer. So, to make it work you should change your layout to (assuming that your entire drawer consists of only one `ListView`):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your xml layout needs to be re-arranged. The `DrawerLayout` should wrap two items; 1) a `View` or `ViewGroup` to set as the page content (e.g., `RelativeLayout` containing a `Toolbar` and `Fragment` container); 2) a `View` or `ViewGroup` that holds your `NavigationDrawer` items (e.g., `ListView`).

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/your_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/your_toolbar_color"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/your_toolbar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/your_drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/your_drawer_color"
        android:divider="@null"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You can get a more detailed explanation and examples here:

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 1):

If your list is empty and you have the height as `wrap_content`, the height will be 0. Changing it to `match_parent` will have it fill the screen regardless of the content.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Bro ..above answer are working..The drawer fully occupied the Screen ..But your Answer is only Exactly right ..Thanks a Lot ..